# Use of pronoun with 'this/that' and possessive

Tags: pronouns

Do we ever say:

> His this answer is right.

---

I've read in grammar books that we say:

> This answer of his.

So, it should be:

> This answer of his is right.

Which one is correct?

---

Secondly, do we use the following structure?

> ***This answer of him is correct.***

Answer (score 2):

> Do we ever say: "His this answer is right."

No, we do not. We might say:

> His answer is right

If it's obvious which answer belongs to him and (probably) he has only submitted one answer.

> So, it should be: "This answer of his is right."

Yes, this is correct.

> Secondly, do we use the following structure? "This answer of him is correct."

Nope, not at all.

"Him" is an object pronoun. If you couldn't use any other noun in that place it wouldn't work. You need the possessive pronoun (or a noun in the possessive form) to show that the answer belongs to the whatever.